# Subject-complement agreement - we regard them as a resident of the UK

Tags: grammar

As stated at INTM162020-30, customers will occasionally ask HMRC for confirmation that *we regard them as a resident of the UK* for purposes other than claiming relief from foreign taxes under the terms of a Double Taxation Agreement.  https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/international-manual/intm162140

To paraphrase, the phrase in question shall be read as *we regard customers as a resident of the UK*. Do 'customers' and 'a resident' agree with each other in that case?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of the plural (non binary) neuter-gender used as a singular (non-binary) neuter-gender.

It allows the writer to avoid the use of **him or her** when referring to a person or people of both genders or either gender (or anything else in-between).

More typically these days, it's the words **they** and **their** that one comes across in this context.

> If anyone is looking for **their** dog, will **they** please come to the desk.

Such usage avoids the sexism associated with the traditional historical use of **he, his** and **him** in contexts such as these.

While many English speakers dislike the practice, it dates back centuries and occurs everywhere in conversation and text.

You will find numerous references to it online.

https://public.oed.com/blog/a-brief-history-of-singular-they/
https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/singular-nonbinary-they